# Menu option appearing when I pressed back Button on fragment

Tags: android

This is my activity, there is no menu option
[image: This is my activity, there is no menu option]
image of when menu option appeaes
[image: image of when menu option appeaes]
image 3
[image]

I have only created menu options in fragment. When i go back n forth the menu also appears in activity.

Comment: Add menu.clear() before inflating menu items.

Comment: It still appears in main activity once.. It wont repeat  like previous. What could be the reason for it to appear.